# Logging to problems log in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

```
PlatformLogUtil.logAsError(Activator.getDefault(), new Status(IStatus.ERROR, "com.sample.example",enter code here "ERROR"));
```

I am using above code for Logging in eclipse problems log.
But it is not visible in problems log but able to see in console.

Can any one suggest is it right what i am performing in above code  or do i need to do some thing else to view in Problem Log in eclipse.

Comment: Where does `PlatformLogUtil` come from?

Comment: PlatformUtil is from "org.eclipse.sphinx.platform.util"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [take a look](https://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/modeling/org.eclipse.mdt.sphinx/trunk/plugins/org.eclipse.sphinx.platform/src/org/eclipse/sphinx/platform/util/PlatformLogUtil.java) at the PlatformLogUtil implementation, you will see, that it does not create any problems, it just logs the error, which is shown in the "Error Log" view.

In order to show a problem in the problem view, you need to create a marker for your problem. Please read "[Mark My Words](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html)" article to get more information on how to do it.

```
void reportError(IResource resource, int line, String msg) {
   IMarker m = resource.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
   m.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line);
   m.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, msg);
   m.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
   m.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will log the error in the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory. The `Error Log` view should also show the error.

If the plugin you pass to `PlatformLogUtil` is `null` (from `Activator.getDefault()`) then the error is sent to the console.